# Partial User Registration on Home Page (index)

Tags: php, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle, user-registration

I am using Symfony2 2.6.4 with the FOS User Bundle (master) and I am having a hard time trying to pass a partial registration from the home page to the registration page.

## The Goal

I want a user to start on the home page and fill out some info and press submit.  I want the user to be passed to the registration page and pre fill the items that they have already filled out on the front page.

Things I have tried:
I am unsure what is feasable and have already spend too much time on this.  I tried extending the registration controller but I am getting errors before I can even start on my issue so I stopped.  My last thought was to pass the variables in a session to the overridden registration form type and see if I can pre-populate it there.

Has anyone done anything like this before?  They sure don't make it easy.

Comment: It should be easy overriding the template just create a your new twig in the same path like this app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register.html.twig and the app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig then you should be able to populate the fields there using the session. {{ app.session.get('myfield') }}

Comment: This worked!  I'll post my answer below.  Thank you @NawfalSerrar !

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to @NawfalSerrar  Thank you for the idea.  I was close but not close enough!

So what I ended up doing was this.

This is the controller action that does that work.

```
/**
 * @Route("/", name="Home")
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new RegisterFormType());

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
        $user = new User();
        $session = $this->get('session');

        $registration = array();
        $registration['firstName'] = $data['first'];
        $registration['lastName'] = $data['last'];
        $registration['middleInit'] = $data['middle'];
        $registration['email'] = $data['email'];
        $session->set('registration', $registration);

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl("fos_user_registration_register"));
    }
    return $this->render('Bundle:Page:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}
```

Then the form on the front end.

```
{{ form_start(form,{'attr': {'class': 'reg-page'}}) }}
  <div class="reg-header">
      <h1>Get Started!</h1>
      <p>Already Signed Up? Click <a href="page_login.html" class="color-green">Sign In</a> to login
          your account.</p>
  </div>
  {{ form_errors(form) }}
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          {{ form_label(form.first) }}
          {{ form_widget(form.first, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control margin-bottom-10'}}) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          {{ form_label(form.middle) }}
          {{ form_widget(form.middle, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control margin-bottom-10'}}) }}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
          {{ form_label(form.last) }}
          {{ form_widget(form.last, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control margin-bottom-10'}}) }}
      </div>
  </div>
  {{ form_label(form.email) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.email, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 text-right">
          {{ form_widget(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'btn-u'}}) }}
      </div>
  </div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Registration page looks like this.

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% set tokens = app.session.get('registration') %}
    {% if tokens['firstName'] is defined %}
        {% set firstName = tokens['firstName'] %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if tokens['middleInit'] is defined %}
        {% set middleInit = tokens['middleInit'] %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if tokens['lastName'] is defined %}
        {% set lastName = tokens['lastName'] %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if tokens['email'] is defined %}
        {% set email = tokens['email'] %}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_start(form) }}
    {{ form_errors(form) }}

    {{ form_label(form.firstName, 'First Name', {label_attr: {class: 'foo'}}) }}
    {% if firstName is defined %}
        {{ form_widget(form.firstName, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}, value : firstName  }) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.firstName, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'} }) }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_label(form.middleInitial) }}
    {% if middleInitial is defined %}
        {{ form_widget(form.middleInitial, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}, value : middleInit }) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.middleInitial, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}}) }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_label(form.lastName) }}
    {% if lastName is defined %}
        {{ form_widget(form.lastName, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}, value : lastName }) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.lastName, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}}) }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ form_label(form.email) }}
    {% if email is defined %}
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}, value : email }) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { attr: {class: 'TestClass'}}) }}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
    {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}"/>
    </div>
    {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Hope this helps!